# Magento 2 checkout Plugin, how to?

Tags: magento2, checkout, sales, plugin

I'd like to hook into the save process of an order, so that I can execute my own code once the order is completed.

So far I've done similar things with the Customer and CustomerAdress Objects using the Plugin Pattern and a aroundSave method.

I'd like to do the same for the order object on checkout, but I can't seem to get an overview on how the mechanisms work. There are just too many new design patterns and methods stacked over each other (Knockout, Component, Rest, Zendframework).

I've tried making a Plugin for Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order but it has no effect.

Does anybody have an idea how I can find the correct class to hook up with the plugin class?

Comment: What did you end up doing? I want to implement a call to an external API that purchases the order on my behalf (similar to dropshipping), and I face the same problem. I do not know if I should do a plugin after capture, place order or order save.

Comment: instead of the save method, I hooked into beforeSave() and afterSave().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue as you. I think in the case of placing an order it is better to stick with the Event/Observer pattern, as Magento2 has its own event for that. So what I have done in my code is to create an observer like this:

```
class PlaceOrderObserver implements ObserverInterface
{
   public function execute(Observer $observer) {
      // Do your stuff here
   }
}
```

And the events.xml something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
   <config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
      <event name="sales_order_payment_place_end">
         <observer name="someObserver" instance="My\Space\Observer\PlaceOrderObserver" />
   </event>
</config>
```